Two facts about density and closure
I'd like to know if these facts of general topology are true, because I think that they are implicitly used in a course about schemes that I'm following, but I'm not sure that the following are precisely the results being used, as I don't have a solid background in topology.
Let $X$ be a topological space. Let $x\in X$ and let $x\in U\subset X$ be an open dense subset containing $x$.
Fact 1. Denote the closure of $x$ in $X$ by $\bar x ^X$ and the closure of $x$ in $U$ by $\bar x^U$. Is it true that
$\bar x^U=\bar x ^X\cap U$?
Fact 2. Let $Z,Z'\subset X $ be two closed subsets. Is it true that $Z\cap U=Z'\cap U$ implies $Z=Z'$?

I find your question somewhat unclear, as you seem to be using $x$ to refer to a subset of a topological space and to an element of that topological space. Also it would be clearer to refer to $X_1$ and $X_2$, since $X'$ often means the set-theoretic complement of $X$. If I understand you correctly though a counter-example in the real number system for "Fact" 2 is if $Z_1=[0,2]$, $Z_2=[0,3]$ and $U=(0,1)$

Fact 1 is true, more generally: let $A \subset M \subset X$. Then the closure of $A$ in $M$ equals $\overline{A} \cap M$. Left-hand side with respect to the subspace topology of $M$, of course. Note that $M$ need not be open or dense.

@Peter: your set $U$ is not dense, but $U = \mathbb R \setminus {0}$, $Z = \emptyset$, $Z^\prime = {0}$ provides a counterexample.

@Ulli thanks for the observation. Maybe this is the fact I'm looking for: given $Z\subset X$ closed and $U\subset X$ open dense, with $x\in Z$ and $x\in U$, is it true that  $Z\cap U=\bar x^U$ implies $Z= \bar x^X$?
